# Multiple *ngFor to iterate the arrays in <td>

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, ngfor

Attribute Interpolation in Angular 7

Here is my employee.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.scss']
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
  tableTitle = 'Team Details';
  public employeeID: string;
  public employeeName: string;
  public employeeDepartment: string;
  public employee = [this.employeeID = '100', this.employeeName = 'Ankit', this.employeeDepartment = 'ABCD'];
  public employee1 = [this.employeeID = '101', this.employeeName = 'Amar', this.employeeDepartment = 'ABCD'];
  public employee2 = [this.employeeID = '102', this.employeeName = 'Suraj', this.employeeDepartment = 'ABCD'];
  public employee3 = [this.employeeID = '103', this.employeeName = 'Guru', this.employeeDepartment = 'PQR'];
  public employee4 = [this.employeeID = '104', this.employeeName = 'Shubham', this.employeeDepartment = 'PQR'];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

Here is my employee.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <table  align="center" class="table table-striped table-dark">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3">  {{tableTitle}}
          </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Employee ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Employee Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Designation</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr *ngFor="let employees of employee">
        <th scope="row">{{employees.employeeID}}</th>
          <td align="center">{{employees.employeeName}}</td>
          <td align="center">{{employees.employeeDepartment}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">101</th>
          <td align="center">Amar</td>
          <td align="center">Software Engineer</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">102</th>
          <td align="center">Guru</td>
          <td align="center">Software Engineer</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">103</th>
          <td align="center">Shruti</td>
          <td align="center">Software Engineer</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th scope="row">104</th>
          <td align="center">Suraj</td>
          <td align="center">Trainee</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I need to traverse all the employee arrays and run a *ngFor for every array and add data individually within the   tag.

Can someone please help me with my code. By rewriting it or by giving a possible solution for the same. I don't want to use andy JSON
 file or any `MAT_TABLE`. Just want to stick to the basics and interpolate the data from .ts file to .html file from the arrays.

Comment: why you are using different arrays for every record, any reason?

Comment: are you retrieving this data from server???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what exactly are you doing with so many arrays in your Component Code. Each employee property that you have in your Component is an array and it has a key and assigned values to them using a `=`.

What you should be having instead is an array of JavaScript Objects.

Try this in your Component Class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  tableTitle = 'Team Details';

  employees = [
    { employeeID: '100', employeeName: 'Ankit', employeeDepartment: 'IM SGGS' },
    { employeeID: '101', employeeName: 'Amar', employeeDepartment: 'IM SGGS' },
    { employeeID: '102', employeeName: 'Suraj', employeeDepartment: 'IM SGGS' },
    { employeeID: '103', employeeName: 'Guru', employeeDepartment: 'IM SGGS' },
    { employeeID: '104', employeeName: 'Shubham', employeeDepartment: 'IM SGGS' },
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

And in your Template:

```
<div class="container">
    <table align="center" class="table table-striped table-dark">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3">
                    {{tableTitle}}
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Employee ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Employee Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Designation</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr *ngFor="let employees of employees">
                <th scope="row">{{employees.employeeID}}</th>
                <td align="center">{{employees.employeeName}}</td>
                <td align="center">{{employees.employeeDepartment}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wtyspx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: what did you add in component , i dont see any changes? Can you explain bit more

Comment: @PardeepJain, OP has multiple arrays in his Component. And each array has key value pairs for some reason. I've created an array of objects instead.

Comment: @SiddAjmera  your answer is somewhat correct. but issue is with data is has.

Comment: @SiddAjmera ahhha, yeah preety cool. Same suggested by me in comments :)

Comment: @PardeepJain, actually the arrays that the OP is using aren't really arrays. I have a strong feeling that OP wanted to use `{ }` but by mistake ended up using `[ ]`. Frankly speaking, it took me some time to notice that he used `[ ]` instead of `{ }` :D